# ECHO JSON WITH PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this json and I need to echo some specific results from it with php

JSON

```
{
totalResultsCount: 1,
geonames: [
        {
        adminCode1: "06",
        lng: "27.85849",
        geonameId: 953781,
        toponymName: "Soweto",
        countryId: "953987",
        fcl: "P",
        population: 1695047,
        countryCode: "ZA",
        name: "Soweto",
        fclName: "city, village,...",
        countryName: "South Africa",
        fcodeName: "populated place",
        adminName1: "Gauteng",
        lat: "-26.26781",
        fcode: "PPL"
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I echo lets say name which is in geonames[]

I tried this

```
<?php

echo $json->geonams->name
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json object in two ways:

**1. json object style:**

echo $json->geonams->name;

**2. array style:**

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);    // it will return an array
echo $arr['geonams']['name'];
```

Comment: I will mark this as answer as i think it came close to what I got in the end

Comment: Looking at the json, `$json->geonames` is an array, which makes 1. `$json->geonames[0]->name` and 2. `$arr['geonames'][0]['name]`.

Comment: geonames is a collection of subarrays, therefore you require the index of [0] as @MagnusEriksson points out. Update your answer for +1